# HttpResponseForbidden and handler403

Tags: python, django, http

Currently using Django, I created a small piece of code to show the user a custom error page for 404/500/403 Http Responses.
`urls.py`

```py
from apps.me_report.views import ClientErrorView
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found, server_error, permission_denied
handler404 = ClientErrorView.as_view(default=page_not_found)
handler403 = ClientErrorView.as_view(default=permission_denied)
handler500 = ClientErrorView.as_view(default=server_error)
```

When someone who is in the staff, the default method is called which is nice to see the actual error. But when I return something like this :
`return http.HttpResponseForbidden('<h1>Forbidden</h1>')`
It seems like the handler403 doesn't act in such cases. Why is that ? And how can I make this response to be treated as the other 403 responses ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those handlers are only invoked on exceptions, not simply returning a response with a different HTTP status. Rather than returning HttpResponseForbidden, you need to raise PermissionDenied:

```
from django.core import exceptions

raise exceptions.PermissionDenied
```

Comment: Just tried to change the returns with that, but it seems like Django is still returning me the `<h1>Forbidden</h1>` instead of displaying my error page. Could there be something more that I didn't do right ?

Comment: Sorry I forget some of those returns. Thanks a lot, it's amazing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman : every django answer has your presence....r u one of the co-founders of this MVC?? ;)